# How to merge 2 JSON files?

Tags: python, json, postgresql

There are two different JSON files.

```
[{"volume": "44", 
"affiliations": {}, 
"cite_count": 39, 
"issue": "12", 
"page_range": "1257-1271", 
"doi": "10.1016/0584-8547(89)80124-7", 
"title_en": "test"}
]

[{"sourceType": "Conference Proceeding", 
"page_range": "1257-1271",
"language": null, 
"volume": null, 
"titleEn": "test2", 
"spinCiteCount": null}
]
```

As you see, they have same information, but in different forms. Some information is not in other file. 
I need to convert all of them into one postgreSQL table(or JSON file and parse it).

So, what should I do to merge different formats JSON files into one file or one postgres table with Python?

Comment: are they keyed on the `page_range` field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just merge both into a single dictionary / json:

```
import json

dic1 = json.load('json_file_1')
dic2 = json.load('json_file_2')
dic1.update(dic2)

print dic1
```

Output:

```
{
  "volume": "44", 
  "affiliations": {}, 
  "cite_count": 39, 
  "issue": "12", 
  "page_range": "1257-1271", 
  "doi": "10.1016/0584-8547(89)80124-7", 
  "title_en": "test2"
  "sourceType": "Conference Proceeding", 
  "language": None, 
  "volume": None, 
  "spinCiteCount": None
}
```

> Note: the common keys will be overwritten by the values of the second
>   file. So the order you read the files matters, based on what you need,
>   change the order.